# How do I change the contents of a div inside a modal dialog using JQuery

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I have the following jQuery dialog and I want to change the contents of a div inside the dialog just before I open it. However I can't seem to fathom it out, can any one help?

```
<div id="dialog" title="Basic dialog">
<div id="data"></div>
</div> 

$("#dialog").dialog({
    bgiframe: true, height: 140, modal: true, autoOpen: false
});

$("#data").html = "My new text"; /*THIS DOES NOT WORK*/
$("#dialog").dialog('open');
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use

```
$("#data").html("My new text");
```

not `$("#data").html = "My new text";`. There is no property `html` on a jQuery object. Instead there is a function [`html(val)`](http://docs.jquery.com/Attributes/html#val) to set the html content, of every element matched with the selector (in your case `#data`.

Comment: +1 for answer, boy I couldn't see the trees through the fog! I am such a gimp! Many thanks